# Laravel 5.1: Try catch block not catching custom exception with SOAP API source

Tags: php, laravel, soap, laravel-5

We have created an API that connects to the SOAP API system of the customer. We have a custom exception CustomerNotFound :

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

class CustomerNotFoundException extends  \Exception
{
    protected $code = 'customer_not_found';
    protected $message = 'Customer not found!';
}
```

A Soap Class function for retrieving user information

```
public function getCustomerById($customerID)
    {

        $parameters = $this->appendToParameters([
            'customerID' => $customerID])
            ->getParameters();

        $result = $this->client->GetCustomerByID($parameters);

        if ($result->SDKResult->ResultCode === 'Success') {
            $data = $result->GetCustomerByIDResult;

            return $data;
        }

        throw new CustomerNotFoundException();

    }
```

And a controller that calls the soap class function:

```
public function getCustomerDetails(Request $request, $customerId)
    {
        try {
            $customerDetails = $this->customerService->getCustomerById($customerId);

            return $this->respond($customerDetails);

        } catch (\SoapFault $e) {
            $this->respondInternalError($e->getMessage());
        } catch (\App\Exceptions\CustomerNotFoundException $c) {
             $this->respondNotFound($c->getMessage());
        }
}
```

I know the exception is working because when the soap function is also called on another controller, it works and then catches the exception properly when an invalid customer id is given. Also when I remove the try catch block and call the controller function with and invalid id, the api returns the CustomerNotFound exception. However, when it is inside a try catch block it just returns a STATUS 200 and an empty response (no jJSON, etc.). No errors are shown. Any ideas?

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Response;
use JWTAuth;


class ApiController extends Controller 
{

    protected $statusCode = 200;


    public function isDevMode(){
        return request()->get('__devmode__', null) == 'ph';
    }

    public  function  err($msg, $code = 'error'){
        return $this->respond([
            'data'=> null,
            'status'=> [
                'code'=> $code,
                'msg'=> $msg,
                'success'=> false
            ]
        ]);
    }

    public function ok($data =[],$msg='Success',$code='success'){
        return $this->respond([
            'data'=> $data,
            'status'=> [
                'code'=> $code,
                'msg'=> $msg,
                'success'=> true
            ]
        ]);
    }

    public function getStatusCode()
    {
        return $this->statusCode;
    }

    public function setStatusCode($statusCode)
    {
        $this->statusCode = $statusCode;

        return $this;
    }

    public function respondNotFound($message = 'Not Found.',$code='not_found')
    {

        return $this->setStatusCode(404)->respondWithError($message,$code);
    }

    public function respondInternalError($message = 'Internal Server Error.', $code='internal_server_error')
    {

        return $this->setStatusCode(500)->respondWithError($message,$code);
    }

    public function respond($data, $headers = ['Content-type'=> 'application/json; charset=utf-8'])
    {

        return Response::json($data, $this->getStatusCode(), $headers);
    }

    public function respondWithError($message, $code = 'error')
    {

        return $this->respond([
            'error' => [
                'code' => $code,
                'message' => $message
                // 'status_code' => $this->getStatusCode()
            ]
        ]);
    }

    public function getUserTokenDetails()
    {
        $token = JWTAuth::getToken()->get();
        try {

        if (! $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()) 
        {
            return response()->json(['user_not_found'], 404);
        }
        } 
        catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException $e) 
        {
            $this->setStatusCode(401);
            return $this->respondWithError('Token has expired.','token_expired');
        } 
        catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException $e) 
        {
            $this->setStatusCode(401);
            return $this->respondWithError('Token is invalid','token_invalid');
        } 
        catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException $e) 
        {
            $this->setStatusCode(401);
            return $this->respondWithError('Token not found.','token_not_found');
        }
        $payload = JWTAuth::parseToken()->getPayload();
        $user = $payload['customClaims']; 
        return $user['CUST_ID'];
    }

}
```

Comment: May be exception is being caught but $this->respondNotFound($c->getMessage()); is not working. To check whether exception is working or not, change your catch block to: catch (\App\Exceptions\CustomerNotFoundException $c) {
             throw $c; $this->respondNotFound($c->getMessage());
        }       i.e. add throw $c to check whether exception is being caught or not.

Comment: @MuhammadInaamMunir Thanks let me try

Comment: Please let me know if problem gets solved. :)

Comment: @MuhammadInaamMunir it throws the not found exception but I have to format the error in the proper way that is why there is `$this->respondNotFound($c->getMessage());` how should I do this?

Comment: Please show the code of function ( respondNotFound )

Comment: @MuhammadInaamMunir should be shown above